# cumsum on all non grouped vars

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

(using native pipe)

A dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(
  id = c('a','a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b'),
  x = 1:6,
  y = rnorm(6),
  z = rnorm(6)
)
```

Within the group of id, I want to arrange by x then take the cumsum of both y and z. I don't want to specify y and z, instead I want to tell dplyr 'just cumsum everything that's not a grouping var'.

Attempts:

```
df |> 
  group_by(id) |> 
  arrange(x) |> # should not be cumsumed
  # mutate(all_vars(), cumsum)
  #mutate(across(any_vars()), cumsum)
  # mutate(across(everything()), cumsum)
```

How can I get to this?

Comment: It is a bit confusing, you say both to `cumsum` all non-group vars, but `x` is not a group var, but you do not want the `cumsum` of `x`. This is a contradiction.

Comment: `group_vars()` may be helpful.  See [here](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/grouping.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be one way:

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = F)
set.seed(1)
data.frame(
  id = c('a','a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b'),
  x = 1:6,
  y = rnorm(6),
  z = rnorm(6)
) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  arrange(x) %>% 
  mutate(
    across(-x, cumsum, .names = '{.col}_cumsum')
  )
#> # A tibble: 6 × 6
#> # Groups:   id [2]
#>   id        x      y      z y_cumsum z_cumsum
#>   <chr> <int>  <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1 a         1 -0.626  0.487   -0.626    0.487
#> 2 a         2  0.184  0.738   -0.443    1.23 
#> 3 a         3 -0.836  0.576   -1.28     1.80 
#> 4 b         4  1.60  -0.305    1.60    -0.305
#> 5 b         5  0.330  1.51     1.92     1.21 
#> 6 b         6 -0.820  0.390    1.10     1.60
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I tried that just now, but it looks like y, z are not the cumulative sum. Will edit my post to illustrate

Comment: @DougFir Yes they are... I've included the original columns instead of in-place modifiction

Comment: You are correct! Sorry, I scanned too fast and never noticed the groups reset the cumsum. Thank you!